# Python Pandas Dataframe Using Columns and altering Categorical-data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

I'm trying to accomplish the following tasks:

1)Create a barplot showing the mean number of speakers grouped by degree of endangerment(Using a log scale for the numerical axis).

2) Group the data by degree of endangerment and calculate and print descriptive statistics for the number of speakers for each category of degree of endangerment

Essentially, I have a dataframe that I am working on and Number of speakers ,degree of endangerment, and number of speakers are columns within my dataframe. I have the following code to make the Degree of endangerment column be categorical

```
df.Categorical(['Degree of endangerment'], categories = ("Vulnerable", "Definitely endangered", "Severely endangered", "Critically endangered", "Extinct")
```

Firstly, How do I make a barplot that takes the mean(avg) data of a column and references it to a categorical column object? There are no NAN types in my data.

Secondly, how do I exactly modify my dataframe to be grouped based off of a categorical variable/column?

Comment: For plotting, I would take a look at the seaborn package. It expects data organized that way. As for the second point, `groupby` method is probably what you'll want, although I'm not exactly sure what you want.

Comment: It is unlikely you will get an answer unless you include an excerpt of your data frame (3-5 rows).